# What are strategies for not making Eclipse RCP based application look like IDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there example for Eclipse RCP based application that doesn't look like engineering tool, but rather more friendly to a regular user, so I could learn from it (open source preferred)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great example of what is possible with Eclipse RCP is [Lotus Notes 8](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264877&wv=1):

- [Lotus Notes gets a facelift](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9019476/Lotus_Notes_gets_a_facelift_Version_8_beta_review_and_visual_tour)
- [Why choosing eclipse for notes 8 was the right choice](http://lekkimworld.com/2011/05/18/why_choosing_eclipse_for_notes_8_was_the_right_choice.html)

I am not sure how they adapted the UI but assume they used the [Presentation API](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/presentations/package-summary.html) and did some manual SWT work.

You might be interested in [Eclipse Riena](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Riena/Look_and_Feel).
From the [project page](http://www.eclipse.org/riena/):

> ...the Riena user interface components will support a business process oriented user interface visualization and navigation metaphor which can be used as alternative to the default workbench layout.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want ot take a look at the following two presentations:

- “RCP Custom Look and Feel” - http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/RCP_Custom_Look_and_Feel - from the Eclipse Wiki will give you a good starting point to some of the possible strategies. It does not cover all strategies - e.g. theming and e4...
- “Changing the look and feel of Eclipse applications” - download : http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.ui.examples.presentation/eclipsecon2005-presentationsAPI.ppt?revision=1.1&view=co - a presentation from EclipseCon 2005 that describes the basic ideas behind the Presentation API. Note though that the only real way to create a new presentation, is to clone one of the existing ones and and then start modifying the code.

If you want to use CSS styling, when consider using Eclipse 4 (often dupped e4) as the basis for your application. Here you have a very large degree of freedom!

Good luck!

Comment: I looked at e4 samples, all of them remind Eclipse IDE (even when colored differently with CSS).

Comment: It all depends on how different a look you want for your application. If you want some style your application like winamp or similar, I really don't think Eclipse RCP is the right starting point as a framework. At least that is what I normally teach people in RCP classes.